# Logic forgets my controller assignments when I disconnect the MIDI interface

Tags: usb, midi, logic

I have a Roland A-800PRO-R MIDI keyboard that I connect to my MacBook over USB.

I can use Logic's controller assignments tool to assign effects such as volume, reverb, or EQ to the physical knobs and faders on my keyboard. But if I disconnect the keyboard and plug it back in, Logic ignores the assignments listed on the screen and instead creates a new A-800PRO-R profile with non-customized assignments.

Has anyone else encountered this, and is there a way to force Logic to remember my device?